# Need help writing a regex string to remove string with variable number

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

Ok I want to remove all text that is a variable length number between 2 fixed strings.  so for example:  lets say I needed to remove the following paterns:

`::tt::23559::/tt::`

or

`::tt::123::/tt::`

I've tried a few combinations I can`t get it right I'm using PHP:

```
$string = preg_replace('::tt::[^0-9]+::/tt::', '', $string );
$string = preg_replace('::tt::/([0-9]/)::/tt::', '', $string );
$string = preg_replace('::tt::[0-9]+::/tt::', '', $string );
```

And many other variations, I'll continue hacking but if anyone knows the right syntax off the top of their head I'd appreciate.

Comment: You forgot to set delimiters ! So `$string = preg_replace('#::tt::\d+::/tt::#', '', $string );` would do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include a [pattern delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) (in this case `~`):

```
$string = preg_replace('~::tt::[0-9]+::/tt::~', '', $string );
```